# Long and wide table over multiple page latex

Tags: tables, pdftex, longtable, overleaf, multicolumn

I want to have a latex table that consists of several columns that need to span over multiple pages by breaking columns. In addition, the table is also long that needs to distribute over multi-pages. Is there any possible package to implement this requirement?

Comment: I believe the short answer to your question is "no". Your second requirement (length, distribute material across several pages) can actually be met fairly easily with the `longtable` package and eponymous environment, as well as other environments such as the `xltabular` environment. How wide is your table in practice? Could its width be accommodated by switching from portrait to landscape format? Why is your table so wide to begin with? How many columns are in the table? Do you allow automatic line breaking in cells?

Comment: IMHO, you have a table in excel or similar software with many rows and columns. There are sliders to enable reading data on the monitor. But sliders are impossible on the printed document. You have to rearrange the data in order to create a result where data are comfortably read. Only human is able to do this because only human know the meaning of data. You must decide what is important and what not, how to split data to more tables, what must be repeated on more pages etc. Automaton is unable to do this.

Comment: My table has 8 columns and 26 rows. The cells contain mostly textual information and sometimes it contains explanatory texts. Texts may break in the cell. Thank you @Mico

Comment: Thank you @wipet